# missing keys in HKEY_Classes_root when running as a service

Tags: c#, windows-services, registry

I am developing a c# .net 3.5 windows service on Windows 8 x64.

I need to see if a specific package id is under the node HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ActivatableClasses\Package.

This is the code

```
internal static bool IsPackageInstalled
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                var packageKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"ActivatableClasses\Package");
                if (packageKey != null)
                {
                    return packageKey.GetSubKeyNames().Any(key => key.StartsWith(MyPackageName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                }                                                                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {


            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

When running this code in a console application it works ok and returns true.

But when running the code within a Windows service, I am getting false. I tried to debug it and I saw that in a service the list of subkeys names contains only 2 keys, while there are actually 21 sub keys.

what could have caused this behavior?

**UPDATE:**
The problem is that the service is running under a different user, and therefore every package that appears only under HKEY_CURRENT_USER won't appear when the service queries the registry.

Is there a way for the service to check another user registry (even if the user is not currently logged in)?

Comment: Do you see the extra keys in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`? `HKEY_Classes_Root` is a combination of local machine and user classes.

Comment: What architecture is your application being compiled to? x86 or x64?

Comment: These are Windows Store app keys, I'd definitely assume security preventing you from hacking them.  Try it with a different user account for the service.

Answer (score 1):

The `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` key is actually a virtual key that amalgamates two others keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes
```

It's most likely the values you want exist under the USER portions. Remember that services do not run under the context of a normal user like your console application.

For more information on the registry keys see here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475(v=vs.85).aspx

You can however set the service to run as a specific user which does have these values.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that it has to do with permissions.  Different areas of the registry have differing permissions.  As a troubleshooting step i would try running my service as another user to see if the results change.  If so, then you might want to look into impersonation.